# Add Link to Users List (Backend) to open each users front-end profile

Tags: functions, users, front-end, dashboard, profiles

As default the Users Screen in the Backend allows me to add, change, or delete my site's users:

[image]

Now i need a additional url in the user list, wich redirects me to each users **front-end profile (e.g. www.mysite.com/author/anna/)**. I was not able to find anything in the wordpress codex or online. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will add a "View author profile" link to the row actions (i.e., the links that appear when you hover over the username):

```
add_filter ('user_row_actions', 'add_view_author_page', 10, 2) ;

function
add_view_author_page ($actions, $user)
{
    $href = esc_attr (get_author_posts_url ($user->ID)) ;
    $actions['add_view_author_page'] = "<a href='$href'>View author page</a>" ;

    return ($actions) ;
}
```

**Edit:**

Or if you prefer to have the link in column of the table, you could do:

```
add_filter ('manage_users_columns', 'users_columns') ;
add_filter ('manage_users_custom_column', 'users_custom_column', 10, 3) ;

function
users_columns ($cols)
{
    $cols['author_page'] = 'Author page' ;

    return ($cols) ;
}

function
users_custom_column ($default, $column_name, $user_id)
{
    if ('author_page' == $column_name) {
        $href = esc_attr (get_author_posts_url ($user_id)) ;
        $default .= "<a href='$href'>View</a>" ;
        }

    return ($default) ;
}
```

Comment: @Learningbydoing oops :-)  Also, I just edited the answer to show how to do it as an additional column to the table...in case you'd prefer it that way (personally, I prefer things like this as a row action)

Comment: Great - the second code has also the same error - pleas remove the bracket again :) Otherwise - just perfect!

Comment: typing too fast